# Japanese animation from 2012: A boy builds a space ship with alien help

Tags: story-identification, anime, animation

All I remember was that I saw it around 2012, and it was in Japanese, about a kid trying to build his own space ship and go to space. In the end when he finally succeeds at the end of the show it turns out that the quiet old man that was cheering him on throughout the whole show turned on to be an alien and his tiny little shop was his spaceship.

Comment: Also this might be completely wrong i watched this a really long time ago

Comment: Estimate on how long ago it was? Was language was it in? Was it dubbed?

Comment: I'm going to suggest [Explorers (1985)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089114/). Not an anime, but it did have some puppetry:

"This space adventure stars Ethan Hawke and River Phoenix as misfit best friends whose dreams of space travel become a reality when they create an interplanetary spacecraft in their homemade laboratory."

Comment: it was about 8 years ago and it was in japanese @NJohnny